# How to Run Shell function (LotusScript Language) in Full Administrator

Tags: shell, lotusscript, pgp

I need to process PGP command line codes using the Shell function (LotusScript Language) in Full Administrator. I manually tried the pgp commands using CMD line and I have  confirmed the issue is the Administrator rights. So how do I trigger the Shell function to run in Administrator mode?

Comment: We can deploy code in either Windows or Linux servers,  as long as we can do PGP encode / decode stuff using Lotus Notes agent. Any Ideas RobertL?

Comment: If everybody could run any code in admin mode programmatically... How much would that "security feature" of the operating system be worth, what do you think? I would suggest to find out, why your code needs admin rights. I am quite sure, that you will find out, the reason is something else... Admin mode is only needed in rare cases...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Fixed the issue by modifying the Java Policy and was able to run the Shell command using JAVA agent. 


    import lotus.domino.*;
    import java.util.*;
    import java.io.*;


    public class PGPCodeBuilderEngine { 

        /**
         * Creates  Encoded  PGP  file from the specified Input file
         */

        public void EncodeFile(String inputFolder, 
String inputName, String outputFolder, 
String outputName,  String passName)
        {    

            try{

                String[] cmd = new String[3];
                cmd[0] = "cmd.exe" ;
                cmd[1] = "/c" ;
                cmd[2] = "pgp --encrypt " + inputFolder + "/" + 
inputName + " --recipient " + passName +
 " --input-cleanup wipe --output " +  outputFolder + "/" + 
                outputName + " --overwrite wipe --status-file " + 
outputFolder + "\\status.log -v";

                // must be run with unrestricted access
                Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
                Process proc = rt.exec(cmd);

                cmd = null;
                rt = null;
                proc = null;

            } catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }finally{
                System.gc();
            }

        }   

    }
```